# AttributeError: module 'helpers' has no attribute 'load_dataset'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror, helper

Tried to import and run `helpers.load_dataset(path)` or `helpers.standardize(list)` but says module `'helpers' has no attribute 'load_dataset'`.

**Tried** ==> !wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/master/intro-to-pytorch/helper.py

Also **tried** ==> !pip install helper but nothing works even after restarting the runtime.

How to make the module `helpers.__()` work ? what I am missing ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mping 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

%matplotlib inline

!wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/master/intro-to-pytorch/helper.py

import helpers

import importlib
importlib.reload(helpers)

image_dir= "./folder"

image_list = helpers.load_dataset(image_dir)


error as:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-66931d7c842b> in <module>
----> 1 image_list = helpers.load_dataset(image_dir)

AttributeError: module 'helpers' has no attribute 'load_dataset'
```

Answer (score 0):

`!wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/master/intro-to-pytorch/helper.py` imports `helper.py`, which has no `load_dataset` method defined within it.

The closest method to the `load_dataset` in the entire [repository](https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch) is `load_data`: https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/blob/adebdc96f04362968144f2ab2a267563c9a2554e/project-tv-script-generation/helper.py#L9

Comment: Nope, not working yet. Can you share your code for loading an image dataset using helper ?